# MySQL JOIN COUNTS from another table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have this two tables:

Table members

```
id  full_name   sex
1   John Smith  1
2   Carol Danvers   2
3   Clark Kent  1
4   Lois Lane   2
5   Diana Prince    2
```

Table member_emails

```
id  member  email
1   1   jsmith@mail.com
2   1   johnsmith@jsa.org
3   2   danvers@marvels.com
4   4   llane@dailyplanet.com
```

I would like to know how many distinct member sex count who has emails, like this table:

```
total   male    female
3       1       2
```

I've already use

```
 SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT e.member) AS total,
 SUM(CASE
    WHEN m.sex = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS "male",
 SUM(CASE
    WHEN m.sex = 2
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS "female"
FROM member_emails e
  JOIN members m ON m.id = (
      SELECT DISTINCT e.member
      FROM members
      WHERE id = e.member
)
```

But it resulted

```
total   male    female
3       2       2
```

As it can't distinct e.member.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SELECT the DISTINCT member ids before joining

> ```
> CREATE TABLE members (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `full_name` VARCHAR(15),
>   `sex` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO members
>   (`id`, `full_name`, `sex`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'John Smith', '1'),
>   ('2', 'Carol Danvers', '2'),
>   ('3', 'Clark Kent', '1'),
>   ('4', 'Lois Lane', '2'),
>   ('5', 'Diana Prince', '2');
>
> CREATE TABLE member_email (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `member` INTEGER,
>   `email` VARCHAR(21)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO member_email
>   (`id`, `member`, `email`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'jsmith@mail.com'),
>   ('2', '1', 'johnsmith@jsa.org'),
>   ('3', '2', 'danvers@marvels.com'),
>   ('4', '4', 'llane@dailyplanet.com');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> COUNT(*) AS total,
> SUM(`sex`= 1) AS male
> ,SUM(`sex`= 2) AS  female
> FROM 
> (SELECT DISTINCT `member` FROM member_email) m_e
> INNER JOIN  members m ON m_e.`member` = m.`id`
> ```
>
> ```
> total | male | female
> ----: | ---: | -----:
>     3 |    1 |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f1ca14b4c8d127e7a158cd32f103918)*